# Solve the differential equation $t^2y''+3ty'-3y=t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation $t^2y''+3ty'-3y=t$
>
> Hint: consider the homogeneous part of the form $t^s$

Following the hint I can sub in and factorize the DE.

$$t^n(s(s-1)+3s-3)=0\Rightarrow s=-3,1$$

This means that my homogeneous solution is:
$y_h=At+B/t^3$

At this point I thought using method of undetermined coefficients or variation of parameters.

Try variation of parameters, which means considering a solution to be $$y=v_1(t)t+v_2(t)/t^3$$

Then using variation of parameters:
$v_1't+v_2'(t)/t^3=0$ and (differentiating t and 1/t^3) $v_1'-3v_2'(t)/t^4=t$. Solving these and integrating for $v_1$ and $v_2$ gives me:

$$v_1=t^2/8+c$$ and $$v_2=-t^5/4+k$$

When I plug everything in get:

$$y=(t^2/8+c)t+(-t^5/4+k)/t^3$$

but the correct solution is:

$$at+bt^{-3}+1/4t\log t$$

Comment: If you used undetermined coefficients, you could try $y_p = A t\log(t)$ (follows from the form that you see in repeated roots with Cauchy-Euler equations)

Comment: How would you come up with this function if I didn't have the answer? I can see that $t$ is in the homogeneous term, so I wouldn't I have to multiply by $t$ to get $y_p=t^2$? @NicholasStull

Comment: The second $(v'_1,v'_2)$-equation should read $$\color{red}{t^2}\cdot(v_1'-3v_2'(t)/t^4)=t,$$ and one can already watch the logarithm arriving in the background... :-)

Comment: @Did thanks, could you tell me where the $t^2$ comes from?

Comment: Well, from $\color{red}{t^2}\cdot y''+\cdots=t$, of course!

Comment: @Did would this imply that the previous term is actually $3t\times (v'_1+v'_2/t^3=0)$?

Comment: ?? Sorry but your last comment does not parse. Anyway, the couple of equations to solve is $$v'_1(t)t+v'_2(t)/t^3=0\qquad t^2(v'_1(t)-3v'_2(t)/t^4)=t.$$

Comment: @Did thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this to be Euler's differential equation and as such I would make the substitution $u=\ln t$ so $t=e^u$. Then
$$y^{\prime}=\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dt}=\frac1t\frac{dy}{du}$$
$$y^{\prime\prime}=-\frac1{t^2}\frac{dy}{du}+\frac1{t^2}\frac{d^2y}{du^2}$$
So out differential equation now reads
$$\frac{d^2y}{du^2}+2\frac{dy}{du}-3y=e^u$$
The homogeneous part is
$$\frac{d^2y_h}{du^2}+2\frac{dy_h}{du}-3y_h=0$$
With solution $y_h=e^{ru}$ provided $r^2+2r-3=(r+3)(r-1)=0$ so the homogeneous part is $y_h=c_1e^{-3u}+c_2e^u$. Since $e^u$ is already a in the homogeneous solution, the particular solution will look like $y_p=Aue^u$. Then $\frac{dy_p}{du}=A(u+1)e^u$, $\frac{d^2y_p}{du^2}=A(u+2)e^u$ and
$$\frac{d^2y_p}{du^2}+2\frac{dy_p}{du}-3y_p=4Ae^u=e^u$$
So $A=\frac14$ and
$$y=\frac14ue^u+c_1e^{-3u}+c_2e^u=\frac14t\ln t+\frac{c_1}{t^3}+c_2t$$

Comment: Thanks, I like this method of solving it. I'm not sure I'd be able to come up with the substitutions in the first line :), after that it follows nicely.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$t^2y''(t)+3ty'(t)-3y(t)=t\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

The general solution will be the sum of the complementary solution and particular solution.

---

$$t^2y''(t)+3ty'(t)-3y(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Assume the solution of this Euler-Cauchy equation will be proportinal to $t^{\lambda}$ for some constant $\lambda$.

Substitute $y(t)=t^{\lambda}$:

---

$$t^2\cdot\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\left(t^{\lambda}\right)+3t\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(t^{\lambda}\right)-3\cdot t^{\lambda}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\left(t^{\lambda}\right)=\left(\lambda-1\right)\lambda t^{\lambda-2}$ and $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(t^{\lambda}\right)=\lambda t^{\lambda-1}$:

---

$$\lambda^2t^{\lambda}+2\lambda t^{\lambda}-3t^{\lambda}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$t^{\lambda}\left(\lambda^2+2\lambda-3\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Assuming $t\ne0$, the zeros must come from the polynomial:

---

$$\lambda^2+2\lambda-3=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(\lambda-1\right)\left(\lambda+3\right)=0$$

So, we get two options:

- $$\lambda-1=0\Longleftrightarrow\lambda=1$$
- $$\lambda+3=0\Longleftrightarrow\lambda=-3$$

Comment: This merely repeats, more verbosely, lines 4-5 of the question.